# How to access data from 1 object in an array of objects - java

Tags: java, object, arraylist

So I am trying to write a basic console banking program in java.

The requirements are 1 superclass Account and 2 subclasses Checking and Savings plus some other features like add new account or view accounts. In order to store multiple objects we have to create an array of objects.

```
public class AccountList {

private Account[] list = new Account[5];
private int i = 0;

public void add(Account a)
{
    if (i < list.length) 
    {
        list[i] = a;
    }
}
```

One of the features is to display the account number and balance of all accounts.

```
public static void main( String args[] )
{
AccountList list = new AccountList();
.
.
.
case 5:
        int i;
        int l = list.getLength();

        for(i = 0; i <= l; i++)
        {
            int act = list[i].getAccount();
            double bal = list[i].getBalance();  
            System.out.println("************");
            System.out.printf("Account %d has balance: %f", accountnumber, 
            balance);
        }
```

How would I pull this data from the object at the correct location? Do I have get methods in the Superclass or the Checking and Savings classes instead of the AccountList class where all of the objects are stored?

example: Say list[1] has an acct # 111 and a balance of 100.00 and list[2] has # 222 and a balance of 200.00.

Comment: You code is confusing and missing some important functionality. `AccountList` is an object, not an array, so you can't access information using `[I]`, it doesn't make sense. Instead, `AccountList` needs to provide some kind of "getter" which takes a `int` and returns the `Account` at the specified location

Answer (score 0):

So two things you need to do to set this up correctly.

First you need a method to get specific accounts from your account list object:

```
public Account getAccount(int index){return list[index];}
```

Second you need [getters and setters](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html) in your `Account` object so that you can read and change the variables.

And then when you want to get a balance out of your `AccountList` object, you would do so like this:

```
 //get balance from the first account
 list.getAccount(0).getBalance();
```